# errorr installing pyobjc on Anaconda python on OSX 10.10.2

Tags: python, python-2.7, osx-yosemite, anaconda, pyobjc

I have Python 3.3.5 :: Anaconda 2.1.0 (x86_64) on Mac OS X 10.10.2 with XCode 6.2 (6C131e) and pip 6.0.8

I'm trying to install PyObjC following the [guide](http://pythonhosted.org/pyobjc/install.html). However when I do

```
pip install -U pyobjc
```

I get the following error:

```
$ pip install -U pyobjc
Requirement already up-to-date: pyobjc in ./anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyobjc-3.1-py2.7.egg
Downloading/unpacking py2app>=0.9 (from pyobjc)
  Downloading py2app-0.9.tar.gz (1.7MB): 1.7MB downloaded
  Running setup.py (path:/private/var/folders/hc/fbm2svb951n5wr35bnw_qyqr0000gn/T/pip_build_user/py2app/setup.py) egg_info for package py2app

    warning: no directories found matching 'doc/_static'
    warning: no directories found matching 'doc/_templates'
    warning: no previously-included files matching '.DS_Store' found anywhere in distribution
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyc' found anywhere in distribution
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyo' found anywhere in distribution
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*.so' found anywhere in distribution
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*.dSYM' found anywhere in distribution
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*.dSYM/*' found anywhere in distribution
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*__pycache__*' found anywhere in distribution
    no previously-included directories found matching 'examples/*/build'
    no previously-included directories found matching 'examples/*/dist'
    no previously-included directories found matching 'examples/*/*/build'
    no previously-included directories found matching 'examples/*/*/dist'
    no previously-included directories found matching 'examples/*/*/*/build'
    no previously-included directories found matching 'examples/*/*/*/dist'
Requirement already up-to-date: pyobjc-core==3.1 in ./anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyobjc_core-3.1-py2.7-macosx-10.5-x86_64.egg (from pyobjc)
Requirement already up-to-date: pyobjc-framework-AddressBook==3.1 in ./anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyobjc_framework_AddressBook-3.1-py2.7-macosx-10.5-x86_64.egg (from pyobjc)
Requirement already up-to-date: pyobjc-framework-AppleScriptKit==3.1 in ./anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyobjc_framework_AppleScriptKit-3.1-py2.7.egg (from pyobjc)
Requirement already up-to-date: pyobjc-framework-Automator==3.1 in ./anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyobjc_framework_Automator-3.1-py2.7.egg (from pyobjc)
Requirement already up-to-date: pyobjc-framework-CFNetwork==3.1 in ./anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyobjc_framework_CFNetwork-3.1-py2.7-macosx-10.5-x86_64.egg (from pyobjc)
Requirement already up-to-date: pyobjc-framework-Cocoa==3.1 in ./anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyobjc_framework_Cocoa-3.1-py2.7-macosx-10.5-x86_64.egg (from pyobjc)
Requirement already up-to-date: pyobjc-framework-CoreData==3.1 in ./anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyobjc_framework_CoreData-3.1-py2.7.egg (from pyobjc)
Requirement already up-to-date: pyobjc-framework-CoreText==3.1 in ./anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyobjc_framework_CoreText-3.1-py2.7-macosx-10.5-x86_64.egg (from pyobjc)
Requirement already up-to-date: pyobjc-framework-DiskArbitration==3.1 in ./anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyobjc_framework_DiskArbitration-3.1-py2.7.egg (from pyobjc)
Requirement already up-to-date: pyobjc-framework-ExceptionHandling==3.1 in ./anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyobjc_framework_ExceptionHandling-3.1-py2.7.egg (from pyobjc)
Requirement already up-to-date: pyobjc-framework-InstallerPlugins==3.1 in ./anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyobjc_framework_InstallerPlugins-3.1-py2.7.egg (from pyobjc)
Requirement already up-to-date: pyobjc-framework-LatentSemanticMapping==3.1 in ./anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyobjc_framework_LatentSemanticMapping-3.1-py2.7.egg (from pyobjc)
Requirement already up-to-date: pyobjc-framework-LaunchServices==3.1 in ./anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyobjc_framework_LaunchServices-3.1-py2.7.egg (from pyobjc)
Downloading/unpacking pyobjc-framework-Message==3.1 (from pyobjc)
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pyobjc-framework-Message==3.1 (from pyobjc) (from versions: 2.2, 2.2b1, 2.2b2, 2.2b4, 2.3, 2.4, 2.5.1, 3.0.1, 3.0.3, 3.0.4)
Cleaning up...
No distributions matching the version for pyobjc-framework-Message==3.1 (from pyobjc)
```

Googling the error message, I found [this](https://bitbucket.org/ronaldoussoren/pyobjc/issue/102/cant-install-pyobjc-framework-message-on), where it's marked as resolved so I'm not sure how to proceed.

Comment: Interestingly, when I run that same command, I get `    raise VersionConflict(dist,req) # XXX put more info here`.

Comment: I also tried updating conda, nothing changed

Comment: I have this problem. Did anyone reach resolution (similar specs, with python3.4, conda 2.1, OSX 10.9.5)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with installing PyObjC 3.1 using Anaconda can be worked around by setting "MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=10.9" before running pip, as an example:

```
$ MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=10.9 pip install -U pyobjc-core
$ MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=10.9 pip install -U pyobjc
```

There will be a proper fix in pyobjc 3.2, but I don't know yet when that will be released.