# Error installing pyobjc: Anaconda2.1 python3.4 or 2.7, OSX 10.9

Tags: python, macos, anaconda, pyobjc

`sudo pip install pyobjc` returns:

```
      File "/Users/USER/anaconda/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 573, in check_output
        raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd, output=output)
    subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['/usr/bin/xcodebuild', '-version', '-sdk', 'macosx', 'Path']' returned non-zero exit status 1

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/48/0c48tlds0knggddqs9lwf5900000gn/T/pip-build-RZEwHr/pyobjc-core
```

while both

```
easy_install -U pyobjc
```

and

```
python install setup.py install
```

return

```
xcode-select: error: tool 'xcodebuild' requires Xcode, but active developer directory '/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools' is a command line tools instance
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 185, in <module>
    keywords=['Objective-C', 'bridge', 'Cocoa'],
```

... many more lines of output ...
      File "/Users/USER/anaconda/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 1382, in loads
        return Unpickler(file).load()
      File "/Users/USER/anaconda/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 858, in load
        dispatchkey
      File "/Users/USER/anaconda/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 1133, in load_reduce
        value = func(*args)
    TypeError: **init**() takes at least 3 arguments (1 given)

At least a few other people have run into a similar problem:
[errorr installing pyobjc on Anaconda python on OSX 10.10.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29134992/errorr-installing-pyobjc-on-anaconda-python-on-osx-10-10-2)

Has anyone solved it?

Comment: You didn't include the part of the error that has the actual error message from xcodebuild.

Answer (score 2):

Recent versions of OSX ship with a precompiled PyObjc, if you're able to use the Mac version of Python you should be able to import it:
python

```
Python 2.7.6 (default, Sep  9 2014, 15:04:36) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 6.0 (clang-600.0.39)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import objc
>>> objc.__path__
['/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/PyObjC/objc']
```

Comment: Thanks for leading me to this. You appear to be right: i have added to the original post. Do you think I just need to update Xcode?

Comment: Updating Xcode is probably a good idea. It's also important to make sure the Python version you're using corresponds to the C-compiled library you want to load, in this case PyObjc. When using an installer such as `pip`, `easy_install`, MacPorts or Homebrew, systems paths can be altered which determine where you're machine will look first for various executables and libraries.

Comment: I will try this and report back. Thank you.